# Accumulating errors with decimal type?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, rounding-error

I have an application where I accumulate decimal values (both adding and subtracting.)  I use the decimal type rather than double in order to avoid accumulation errors.  However, I've run into a case where the behavior is not quite what I'd expect.

I have x = a + b, where a = 487.5M and b = 433.33333333333333333333333335M.

Computing the addition, I get x = 920.8333333333333333333333334M.

I then have y = 967.8750000000000000000000001M.

I want to assert that y - x = y - a - b.  However,

y - x = 47.0416666666666666666666667

y - a - b = 47.04166666666666666666666675

I thought this kind of error was exactly what the decimal type was intended to avoid, so what's happening here?

Here is code that reproduces the issue:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal a = 487.5M;
        decimal b = 433.33333333333333333333333335M;
        decimal x = a + b;

        decimal y = 967.8750000000000000000000001M;

        Console.WriteLine(y - x);
        Console.WriteLine(y - a - b);
        if (y - x != y - a - b)
            Console.WriteLine("x - y != y - a - b");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

---

There was some discussion in comments as to why these high precisions are necessary, so I thought I'd address in summary here.  For display purposes, I certainly round the results of these operations, but I use decimal for all internal representations.  Some of the computations take fractions along the way, which results in numbers that are beyond the precision of the decimal type.

I take care, however, to try and keep everything stable for accumulation.  So, for instance, if I split up a quantity into three thirds, I take x/3, x/3 and then (x - x/3 - x/3).  This is a system that is accounting for physical quantities that are often divided up like this, so I don't want to introduce biases by rounding too soon.  For instance, if I rounded the above for x=1 to three decimals, I would wind up with 0.333, 0.333, 0.334 as the three portions of the operation.

There are real physical limitations to the precision of what the system can do, but the logical accounting of what it's trying to do should ideally stay as precise as it can.  The main critical requirement is that the sum total quantity of the system should not change as a result of these various operations.  In the above case, I'm finding that decimal can violate this assumption, so I want to understand better why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Comment: The decimal type is more accurate but also has its limits. What is the exact point of using so many decimal positions? Is this actually required or you are asking just to know the true limitations of decimal type?

Comment: @varocarbas, these are actual numbers being computed by an application that's in production.  I was operating under the assumption that simple addition and subtraction like this would always work for decimals, even though they are at the limits of their precision, since addition and subtraction should never require a higher precision to represent the result in the same base.  I can round the results of earlier operations to avoid this excessive precision, but this raises other process questions (i.e. what is the right point at which to round?)

Comment: I am afraid that your statement "work for decimals" is wrong. Any calculation will work as far as it is within the maximum allowed precision. Example: in a type allowing 3 decimal, any operation involving more decimals would be truncated, like 0.333+0.777 or 0.333*0.777; you cannot expect the given type to perform calculations beyond the maximum number of digits it can deal with.

Comment: Regarding rounding, logically, it has to be avoided for intermediate calculations as much as possible (because reduces the accuracy). In the most likely scenario, by accounting for decimal type, you don't need to round intermediate values. Even under your somehow peculiar conditions, you don't seem to have to round any intermediate value (just with rounding the final results should be enough). The number of decimal positions to round to depends upon your expected precision; I personally rarely round above 6 decimals (3-4 for standard applications), but it would depend upon your requirements.

Comment: @varocarbas, yes, it's clearly an issue with multiplication or division, but it's unclear to me why it's an issue with addition and subtraction.  0.333 + 0.777 = 1.110; there is no ambiguity/truncation here unless you're assuming that they are truncated representations of integral fractions.  I'm not worried about that in this case, as the exact quantity the number is representing doesn't matter to me as much as its stability under accumulation.

Comment: I wrote a pretty bad example. But you seem to be right anyway. Let me do some tests.

Comment: Apparently, you were looking for generic information with no true applicability to your exact problem. Also you don't seem to be interested in practical solutions to avoid these kind or problems in the future. Thus, I will delete my answer (was focused on your exact problem and thus if you don't consider it relevant, I don't see the point of keeping it here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# type Decimal is not like the decimal types used in COBOL, which actually store the numbers one decimal digit per nibble, and uses mathematical methods similar to doing decimal math by hand.  Rather, it is a floating point type that simply assumes quantities will not get so large, so it uses fewer bits for exponents, and uses the remaining the bits of 128 rather than 64 for double to allow for greatly increased accuracy.

But being a floating point representation, even very simply fractional values are not represented exactly:  0.1, for example, requires a binary repeating fraction and may not be stored as an exact value.  (It is not, for a double; Decimal may handle that particular value differently, but this is true in general.)

Therefore comparisons still need to be made using typical floating point math procedures, in which values are compared, added, subtracted, etc., by accepting them only to a certain point.  Since there are approximately 23 decimal places of accuracy, select 16 as your standard, for example, and ignore those at the end.

For a good reference, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Precision](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that decimal was floating point under the hood.  That explains the results as there is not a fixed precision at which addition and subtraction are being performed.  It's unfortunate for my application, since I was relying on exactly that assumption in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

The `Decimal` type is a floating-point type which has more bits of precision than any of the other types that have been built into .NET from the beginning, and whose values are all concisely representable in base-10 format.  It is, however, bulky and slow, and because it is a floating-point type it is no more able to satisfy axioms typical of "precise" types (e.g. for any X and Y, `(X+Y-Y)==X` should either return true or throw an overflow exception).  I would guess that it was made a floating-point type rather than fixed-point because of indecision regarding the number of digits that should be to the right of the decimal.  In practice, it might would have been faster, and just as useful, to have a 128-bit fixed-point format, but the `Decimal` type is what it is.

Incidentally, languages like PL/I work well with fixed-point types because they recognize that precision is a function of a *storage location* rather than a *value*.  Unfortunately, .NET does not provide any nice means via which a variable could be defined as holding a `Fixed(6,3)` and automatically scale and shift a `Fixed(5,2)` which is stored into it.  Having the precision be part of the value means that storing a value into a variable will change the number of digits that variables represents to the right of the decimal place.